# What did I get Citizen Patrol for?

Tags: support, badges

https://serverfault.com/users/58001/george-bailey

I don't remember flagging any post on Server Fault. Maybe some other website. This might be an accident. Maybe I did and just don't remember.

It says 11 hours ago which is midnight in my time zone and I certainly was not using Server Fault at midnight. Maybe StackOverflow,, not ServerFault,, Not after 10:30 PM Eastern.

Can somebody shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an update to the rules of the Citizen Patrol badge so when the badges where re-calculated it awarded the badge to you retroactively

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. I asked for my own question to be closed because I figured out after the fact it belonged on SO. http://serverfault.com/questions/212072/solaris-virtual-slices-disks-for-use-with-zfs

Answer (score 3):

This is a retroactive badge, so if you ever flagged anything, ever on ServerFault, you earned the badge. This is new as of yesterday.